# Hyperlink to a folder

Tags: hyperlink

Is there a way to Hyperlink to a folder. I know I can create link to a web address but is there a way to do this to a folder?

```
Hyperlink@@@{
    {"some web address",URL["www.wolfram.com"]},
    {StatusArea["some folder","Path to folder where files are located"],File@FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"FolderName"}]}
}//Column
```

The folder path is not working. Also `StatusArea` is not displaying (Do I need to change some notebook setting?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With file protocol it works:

```
Hyperlink[
   StatusArea["some folder", "Path to folder where files are located"],
   "file://" <> $UserBaseDirectory
]
```

I don't see the problem with status area, can you elaborate? I'm on Win7 v11.3.

[image]

Comment: I think I found the problem in my Notebook. `Options[EvaluationNotebook[],WindowStatusArea]` gives `{WindowStatusArea -> None}` so I changed it to default using `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],WindowStatusArea->Automatic]`. I don't know what caused this change. I have been doing some stuff with `CellPrint` in the notebook, something must have caused the default value to change from `Automatic` to `None` causing `StatusArea` messages to turn off completely.

Comment: @user13892 great, I am glad everything is fine now.