# Hyperlink to Documentation Pages

Tags: documentation

Is there a way to Hyperlink to a documentation pages. Since documentation pages are notebooks, does hyperlinking to these with file protocol opens them in the documentation center with all the documentation properties like all edits made on them are discarded?

Is there a documentation protocol that opens documentations center pages directly?

See: [Hyperlink to a folder](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194546/hyperlink-to-a-folder)

Comment: Evaluating `Hyperlink["ClickHere", "paclet:ref/Set"]` creates a link to the installed documentation for the `Set` command.  Evaluating `Hyperlink["ClickMe", \
"http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html"]` creates a link to the online documentation for the `Set` command.

Comment: @LouisB Thank you it works! if you want credit please provide this as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Just want to note that LouisB's comment also works in textboxes: write some text, highlight the part you want to link, press Cmd + Shift + H (on Mac), and write `paclet:ref/_` or `paclet:tutorial/_`. Easy! Thanks Louis!

To complete the answer, let's incorporate @LouisB's commment:

> Evaluating
>
> ```
>  Hyperlink["ClickHere", "paclet:ref/Set"]
> ```
>
> creates a link to the installed documentation for the Set command. Evaluating
>
> ```
> Hyperlink["ClickMe", "http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html"]
> ```
>
> creates a link to the online documentation for the Set command. – LouisB [Jun 16 '19 at 5:19](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200437/hyperlink-to-documentation-pages#comment518579_200437)

Comment: I added @LouisB's comment, so that your post better answers the question.  It is generally considered OK on this site to poach an answer from a stale comment, provided you give the original author credit.  When I've done it, I often make the answer "Community Wiki" (CW), so that I don't get any rep points from upvotes. In this case, you've added your own idea, so it's probably ok as is.  But if you disagree, you can "roll back" the edit.

Comment: Sounds good to me and thanks for the best practice context!